# Monitor ESXI from pandora fms

Tags: monitoring, server-monitoring

I'm looking for a tool to monitor my servers, Pandora FMS (free version) seems to be good for my needs, but I want to be sure about something; 
- is it possible to monitor Esxi virtual machines from the free version or not ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. You probably want to ask on Software Recommendations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use local or remote monitoring to gather data from your virtual machine in a OS level